# How can I write a left outer join with sub-select in jpql?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpanel, jpql

I'm using hibernate to interact with a Postgres database. The query I'm trying to make selects Products that have not been assigned to a Branch yet. There is a many-to-many relationship between Products and Branches via the `branch_product` table. I can write the query in native SQL:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT bp.product_id
  FROM branch_product bp
  WHERE bp.branch_id = ?
  ) AS sub ON sub.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.tenant_id = ?
  AND sub.product_id IS NULL;
```

The way that query works is by constructing the `sub` table that contains the rows for all Products at the Branch. Then any rows from Product that don't join with `sub` are what I want - the Products that haven't been added to the Branch yet.

I haven't figured out how I can express this query using jpql though. If I use a native query, then the hibernate Entities can't be loaded easily because the json mapping for the columns isn't set up. It would save a lot of work if I could make this query using jpql.

Answer (score 1):

So in Hibernate 6 it is certainly possible to write HQL like:

```
select p.id, ph.n 
from Person p 
left join 
    (select phone.number as n, phone.person as pp from Phone phone) as ph 
    on ph.pp=p
```

which I believe is pretty similar to your query.

But I don't see how it makes sense to do so. It looks to me like your query can easily be rewritten to not use a subquery.

In my example I would write:

```
select p.id, ph.number
from Person p 
left join Phone ph on ph.person=p
```

and in your SQL query I would write:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN branch_product bp
  ON bp.product_id = p.id and bp.branch_id = ?
WHERE p.tenant_id = ?
  AND bp.product_id IS NULL
```

Perhaps I'm missing something I don't see what purpose your subquery is serving.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out how to write the jqpl that I needed:

```
SELECT p
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT bp.product.id as productId
    FROM BranchProduct bp
    WHERE bp.branch.id = :branchId
) AS sub ON sub.productId = p.id
WHERE sub.productId IS NULL
```

I think what tripped me up was the syntax for the inner select. It doesn't work with `SELECT bp FROM BranchProduct bp`. I have to specifically select columns from bp. Gavin's example helped me get on the right path with that.